# wsimport -extension equivalent Apache CFX command?

Tags: java, apache, web-services, jax-ws

I have wsdl and that have non-unique operation signatures. I can create the client with jax-ws with below command(with parameter **-extension**).

```
wsimport -s build/src http://localhost:9080/TestService/test?wsdl -extension
```

How can I generate the client with Apache CFX wsdl2java tool. 
Most of the paces asked to use -validate=none with maven as below.

```
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/my.wsdl</wsdl>
    <validate>none</validate>
</wsdlOption>
```

Is there any way to generate the web service client with **wsdl2java tool with command line**?

Answer (score -1):

In order to generate client you can use wsdl2java like this

```
wsdl2java -client <wsdlURL>
```

Here is the full command description.

> wsdl2java -fe|-frontend  -db|-databinding
>    -wv  -p <[wsdl-namespace
>   =]package-name>* -sn  -b * -reserveClass * -catalog  -d  -compile -classdir 
>   -impl -server -client -clientjar  -all -autoNameResolution -allowElementReferences|-aer<=true> -defaultValues<=class-name-for-DefaultValueProvider> -ant -nexclude * -exsh <(true, false)>
>   -noTypes -dns  -dex <(true, false)> -validate<[=all|basic|none]> -keep -wsdlLocation  -xjc* -asyncMethods<[=method1,method2,...]>* -bareMethods<[=method1,method2,...]>* -mimeMethods<[=method1,method2,...]>* -noAddressBinding -faultSerialVersionUID  -encoding  -exceptionSuper  -seiSuper * -mark-generated -h|-?|-help -version|-v -verbose|-V -quiet|-q|-Q -wsdlList wsdlurl

For more detailed help you can always check [cxf documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html). IMHO, CXF is a well documented project.